# How to get Cell Width according to device wise in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I use Autolayout and UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

My Custom cell and `storyboard` design are in `iPhone8` and `Label` width is 355 but when I run project in `iPhone5` I want width 300 according to iPhone5 wise but when I `NSLog` Label width, still I get 355. 
How I can get `Label` Width 300 in `iPhone5`?

Guys please tell me how can I can get Width of `Label` according to device wise

here my code link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z2bHhKS_s6P6uICqssaW0gNTDGM-p9vL

Please help me

Comment: Instead of hard-coding width, use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` for cell width.

Comment: you are using cell  with its actually returning size of cell from xib.

Comment: Also you can try by registering cell in viewDidLoad, if you register it for tableView and then reuse in cellForRowAtIndex will give you the behavior you want.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan how can i get do that please elaborate.
i think you get my actually problem

Comment: check my answer below and do your amendments. :)

Comment: You can get the cell's actual width in the CellWillAppear delegate tableview delegate.

Comment: are you taking about willDisplayCell delegate method?
if yes, i can not use because willDisplayCell call after cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @AnkurPatel - explain ***why*** you want the size. It's very possible that you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @DonMag
I want width of UILabel Because I want to calculate size of data. To calculate size of data I have to pass font, size of UILabel to calculate size of data

When I use UILabel size to calculate data, I get UILabel size according to iPhone8 in iPhone5. Actually I need UILabel size according to device wise to get perfect size of data

Comment: @AnkurPatel - hmmm... first, the cell and the label frame is not available until the layout engine has rendered it --- which does not happen at `cellForRowAt` or `prepareForReuse`, so you need to re-think your approach. Besides, what are you going to do when the user rotates the device? Or uses split-view? Can you use auto-shrink font scaling? Or simply truncate or clip the text? Or use multi-line labels?

Comment: i simply simply truncate or clip the text and use multi-line labels

Comment: actually my whole cell code is dynamic means some cell has 100 height, cell has 200 height and so on

Comment: after calculation of my data I have to move up below part of UIlabel.

Comment: @AnkurPatel - in general, you are much better off using auto-layout and constraints to handle dynamic sizing of your cells. Nothing you have said here really describes what you're trying to do. It almost sounds like chicken-or-egg... You need the size before you decide what to show, but deciding what to should *should* be what determines the size.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell_iPhone"
                             bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
             forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell_iPhone *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: My app Crash and give below error

reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (CustomCell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'

Comment: got to you nib and check for attributes inspector set CustomCell in reuseIdentifier filed.

Comment: where i get reuseIdentifier ? sorry i do not understand

Comment: @AnkurPatel I clarified reason of the crash in my answer

Comment: after selecting nib you will see view hierarchy in left pane click at your tableViewCell then you will get it in right pane.

Comment: I already set Identifier CustomCell
are you talking about Identifier?

Comment: exactly...i am talking about that one.

Comment: I did its necessary step. I already set Identifier As CustomCell. still i get crash

Comment: No need to set the identifier in xib , if you register it use the same identifier

Comment: okay I got the point then  
use nib name  at place of CustomCell_iPhone please.
  [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell_iPhone"
                             bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
             forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

Answer (score 0):

Printing the cell / subviews frame in `cellForRowAt` gives incorrect  values as the cell is not yet laid , your cells shows correctly but you have to register the cell instead of this line

```
cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

I see below it the correct line and you commented it , if you want to show correct frames print them inside `layoutSubviews` method of the custom cell class , also the xib should contain only one Root Cell so you have to delete one of these cells , if you want to use both for the tableView , then create separate xib for each one

[image]

//

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
   [super layoutSubviews];
   // NSLog here 
}
```

//

Since you have the tableView occupies full width of screen and you set cell margin to 10 from both side then you can use this to get lbl width inside cellForRowAt

```
CGFloat wid = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 20
```

Comment: yes you can delete second one cell. I use layoutSubviews in CustomCell.m but i can not get frame according to device wise

Comment: No it gives the correct value , your file doesn't contain it either

Comment: have i write layoutSubviews in CustomCell.M file?

My UItableView in UIViewControler

Comment: inside CustomCell.M

Comment: -(void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"lblTemp frame3 : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.lblTemp.frame));
}

inside Customcell

2018-08-10 18:51:14.895155+0530 demoCell[11042:6883850] lblTemp frame3 : {{10, 10}, {355, 80}}

I want actual Width in cellForRowAtIndexPath because I have to do some calculation.
And layoutSubviews method call after return cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Hi are you their

Comment: CGFloat wid = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 20 

I can not do this because actually I have many Objects so i can not use hard core 20 Values to get WIdth.

Comment: Actually For demo I use only UILabel in Originally There 2 UILabels One UIImageView and Next to UIImageView there is UILabel so "Khan" sorry I can not use 20 value as a hard core and my cell size is dynamic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177810/discussion-between-ankur-patel-and-sh-khan).

Comment: Don't know what kind of calculation you want , if it's out of cell reference then get a reference to the Vc inside the cell , then do what you want with the help of layoutSubviews

Comment: According to UILabel Width I have to calculate size of data. To calculate size of data I need UIlabel Size which is related to iPhone5 but i get iPhone8 UIlabel size

Comment: in IPhone5 i get iPhone8 UIlabel size
2018-08-10 19:01:21.591964+0530 demoCell[11575:6891249] lblTemp frame3 : {{10, 10}, {355, 80}}

Comment: hi @sh_khan are you their?